# Resistance and temperature relationship

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance

When the temperature changes from $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$, having $\alpha$, and the amount of resistance ($R_1$) in the previous temperature ($\theta_1$), we can calculate $R_2$, the amount of resistance after the change in temperature, in $\theta_2$.
$$R_2=R_1+R_1\alpha(\theta_2-\theta_1) \implies R_1=R_2-R_1\alpha(\theta_2-\theta_1) \tag{*}$$

Alright then, what if the temperature changes from $\theta_2$ to $\theta_1$? Can I repeat the same sentences for it?

When the temperature changes from $\theta_2$ to $\theta_1$, having $α$, and the amount of resistance $R_2$ in the previous temperature ($\theta_2$), we can calculate $R_1$, the amount of resistance after the change in temperature, in $\theta_1$.
$$R_1=R_2+R_2\alpha(\theta_1-\theta_2) \implies R_1=R_2-R_2\alpha(\theta_2-\theta_1) \tag{**}$$

Something's wrong! Putting Equation (*) and (**) together, you'll get $R_1=R_2$ ! Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: We do have MathJax here that makes your equations look better. You can see [the notation page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in [help] for details, if you aren't familiar with it.

Comment: in the limit as the difference in temperature goes to zero there is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes, you have discovered a bit of a problem with taking linearization a bit too literally.

However:

$R_{2} = R_{1}(1 + \alpha (T_{2}-T_{1}))$ in the 'forward' direction, and

$R_{1} = R_{2}(1 + \alpha (T_{1}-T_{2}))$ in the 'reverse' direction.

Taking the 'reverse' expression for $R_{1}$ and substituting in for $R_{1}$ in the 'forward' equation yields:

$R_{2} = R_{2}(1+\alpha (T_{2} - T_{1}))(1-\alpha (T_{2} - T_{1}))$ or

$R_{2} = R_{2}(1-\alpha^{2} (T_{2} - T_{1})^{2})$

In the limit of $T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$ the argument in parentheses goes to 1 to first order in temperature change and indeed $R_{2} = R_{2}$ and $R_{1} = R_{1}$ upon going back and forth.